# Error: "Pattern cannot match values of type 'URLRequest'" in swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

My code was working perfectly in before.. recently i have installed `Alamofire` in other project now below error throwing.

> `Pattern cannot match values of type 'URLRequest'`

**got error in Alamofire in this line:**

> `case .Success(let upload, _, _): \\........here getting error`

**code with error:**

```
 func postImageRequestWithURL(withUrl strURL: String,withParam postParam: Dictionary<String, Any>,withImages imageArray:NSMutableArray,completion:@escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool, _ response:NSDictionary) -> Void) {

        AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in
        // Here is your Image Array
        for (imageDic) in imageArray {
            let imageDic = imageDic as! NSDictionary
            for (key,valus) in imageDic {
                MultipartFormData.append(valus as! Data, withName:key as! String,fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            }
        }
            
        for (key, value) in postParam {
            MultipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }
    }, to: strURL, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), method: .post, headers:["userId":"mfjeriefei","key":"cnhsdnchsj"]) {(result) in
        switch result {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _): \\........here getting error
            upload.uploadProgress(closure: {(progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                    let json = response.result.value as? NSDictionary
                    completion(true,json!);
                }
                else {
                    let json = response.result.value as? NSDictionary
                    completion(false,json!);
                }
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):\\ ............here getting error
            print(encodingError)
            completion(false,[:]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**like below i am calling the method:**

```
func addNewEvents() {
    var ImageArray : NSMutableArray!
    
    let data = ["eventName":"Abhi's Birthday", "eventMessage":"Please come and join us", "eventDate":"15-07-2020", "eventTime":"11:30AM"] as [String : Any]

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let myJsonString  = NSString(data: json, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
        let parameters : [String:String] = ["eventdetails":myJsonString]
        
        print("event add json \(json)")
      
        guard let imageData = pickedImage?.pngData() else { return }
        let ImageDic  = ["eventImage" : imageData]
        ImageArray    = NSMutableArray(array: [ImageDic as NSDictionary])
        postImageRequestWithURL(withUrl: "http://hbfbfhjdbfj/create/event/", withParam: parameters, withImages: ImageArray) { (isSuccess, response) in
            if isSuccess {
                print(response)
            } else {
                print(response)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
 eventdetails: ["eventName":"Abhi's Birthday", "eventMessage":"Please come and join us", "eventDate":"21-07-2020", "eventTime":"11:30AM", "eventEndDate":"21-07-2020", "eventEndTime":"11:00PM", "isAllDayEvent":"false", "isEventRepeatable":"false", "eventAddress":"123 Hyd Rd", "eventCity":"Secbad", "location":["latitude":"-23.345","longitude":"15.234"], "remindersList":["1-day","1-hours"], "eventFrequency":"Never", "numberOfOccurrences":"", "showGuests":true, "status":"Draft", "createGroup":"true", "inviteeType":"individuals",  "groupId":"", "guestList":[["userKey":"ef54983685274366ba339375ecda69df"], ["phoneNumber":"3106198542"], ["phoneNumber":"8188369592"]]] as [String : Any]
```

the postman ouypot:
[image]

I am unable to solve the above error.. please any one help m e to solve the error in updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code with latest alamofire.

```
  func addNewEvents()
    {
        let dict = ["eventName":"Abhi's Birthday", "eventMessage":"Please come and join us", "eventDate":"21-07-2020", "eventTime":"11:30AM", "eventEndDate":"21-07-2020", "eventEndTime":"11:00PM", "isAllDayEvent":"false", "isEventRepeatable":"false", "eventAddress":"123 Hyd Rd", "eventCity":"Secbad", "location":["latitude":"-23.345","longitude":"15.234"], "remindersList":["1-day","1-hours"], "eventFrequency":"Never", "numberOfOccurrences":"", "showGuests":true, "status":"Draft", "createGroup":"true", "inviteeType":"individuals",  "groupId":"", "guestList":[["userKey":"ef54983685274366ba339375ecda69df"], ["phoneNumber":"3106198542"], ["phoneNumber":"8188369592"]]] as [String : Any]

        let pickedImage : UIImage = UIImage.init(named: "ic_sample.png")!
        self.postComplexPictures(url:NSURL.init(string: "http://itaag-env-1.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/create/event/")! as URL , params: dict, imageToUpload: pickedImage) { (arg0) in
            let (_, list, isSuccess) = arg0
            if(isSuccess)
            {
                print(list)
            }
            else{
                print(list)
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the uploading method:

```
 func postComplexPictures(url:URL, params:[String:Any], imageToUpload : UIImage, finish: @escaping ((message:String, list:[[String: Any]],isSuccess:Bool)) -> Void)
    {
        var result:(message:String, list:[[String: Any]],isSuccess:Bool) = (message: "Fail", list:[],isSuccess : false)

        let headers: HTTPHeaders
        headers = ["deviceid": "F139424D-C749-42F6-B804-21BD17E28CE0","userType": "personal","key": "c913136e897b419bab20746de7baab62", "Content-Type":"application/json"]

        AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            let jpegData = imageToUpload.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
            let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
            multipartFormData.append(jsonData, withName: "eventdetails" )
            multipartFormData.append(jpegData!, withName: "eventImage",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        }, to: url, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), method: .post, headers: headers).response{ response in

            if((response.error == nil))
           {
                do
                {
                    if let jsonData = response.data
                    {
                        let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                        let status = parsedData["status"] as? NSInteger ?? 0
                        let msg = parsedData["message"] as? String ?? ""

                        print("parsedData=", parsedData)
                        
                        if(status==1) {
                            result.isSuccess = true
                            result.message=msg
                            if let jsonArray = parsedData["data"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                                result.list=jsonArray
                            }
                        } else {
                            result.isSuccess = false
                            result.message=msg
                        }

                    }
                    finish(result)
                } catch {
                   finish(result)
                }
            } else {
                print("Resonse.error",response.error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                finish(result)
            }
        }
    }
```

Please handle the response as per your convenience.

Comment: hello.. your code looks like working.. but i am unable to use it.. i have updated my post with JSON related code as well.. can u help me with code according to my post

Comment: Sure let me check it again

Comment: here i am unable to use `result ` as well

Comment: @swiftDev I have updated the answer. Please check and let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: here may i know where i am getting my json response

Comment: Print(parsedData)... you can also update the response handling here.

Comment: Can you send me url and actual parameters with values? If possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218142/discussion-between-swiftdev-and-ved-sharma).

Comment: here i am giving api and parameters please take a look continue this discussion in chat

Comment: add given header and `eventdetails ` then u will get eventId as response

Comment: @swiftDev I have updated the code and it's working. Please try at your end. Also, you will need to handle the response as per your API response. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the code.. but its working thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Error is related to a small mistake(i.e .success syntax according to Alomofire, and change AF as Alamofire), I have correct the Syntax as well as code. Now you can use as follows:-**

```
func postImageRequestWithURL(withUrl strURL: String,withParam postParam: Dictionary<String, Any>,withImages imageArray:NSMutableArray,completion:@escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool, _ response:NSDictionary) -> Void) {

          Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in
          // Here is your Image Array
          for (imageDic) in imageArray {
              let imageDic = imageDic as! NSDictionary
              for (key,valus) in imageDic {
                  MultipartFormData.append(valus as! Data, withName:key as! String,fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
              }
          }

          for (key, value) in postParam {
              MultipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
          }
          }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: strURL, method: .post, headers:["userId":"mfjeriefei","key":"cnhsdnchsj"]) {(result) in
          switch result {
          case .success(let upload, _, _): //........here getting error
              upload.uploadProgress(closure: {(progress) in
                  print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
              })
              upload.responseJSON { response in
                  if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                      let json = response.result.value as? NSDictionary
                      completion(true,json!);
                  }
                  else {
                      let json = response.result.value as? NSDictionary
                      completion(false,json!);
                  }
              }
          case .failure(let encodingError)://............here getting error
              print(encodingError)
              completion(false,[:]);
          }
      }
  }
```