# Issue with AF.upload "Pattern cannot match values of type URLRequest”

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I am not able to debug this error in handling response of multipartFormData of AF.upload.
The error 'Pattern cannot match values of type "URLRequest" shows up on the 2 case statements success and failure.

I tried using the two methods described in this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62976628/error-pattern-cannot-match-values-of-type-urlrequest-in-swift) and .responseDecodables suggested in another post. There is not much reference material out there for this error as it relates to AF.upload. Help!

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
    if let param = parameter{
            for (key, value) in param {
                multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }
    }, to:url, usingThreshold:UInt64.init(), method:.post)
    { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, , ):
            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            })
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                Indicator.shared().stop()
                //print(response)
                if let data = response.value as? NSArray{
                  //  //print(data)
                    completion(data,(response.response?.statusCode)!)
                }
                else{
                    completion(nil,(response.response?.statusCode) ?? 0)
                }
            }
            
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            Indicator.shared().stop()
          //  //print(encodingError.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil,0)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your implementation for Alamofire 5 by removing the `result` switch and moving your `response` methods to the end of the chain.

Comment: Jon, can you share an example where response is at the end? I looked through this GitHub post https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire, but didn’t find sample code.

Comment: It looks like every other `upload` example.